# cassandra(3.x) add new node to cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have two vm in same network, I type listen_address and rpc_address in cassandra.yaml file for each node.I have edited only these three property rest of all default settings.
Here how my cassandra.yaml files looking:

```
vm1(ip:192.168.0.35):             vm2(ip:192.168.0.36):
listen_address: 192.168.0.35      listen_address: 192.168.0.36     
rpm_address: 192.168.0.35         rpc_address: 192.168.0.36
seeds: "192.168.0.36"             seeds: "192.168.0.36"
```

And I start both of them and check `bin/nodetool status`
but each node running seperately not talking in each other.
I watch a sample in cassandra 2.1 and these are the only things he did and it works but not mine..

Anyone got idea ? or tried this in cassandra 3.x version ?

EDITED: here is a command message from cassandra that he is handshaking with the other node:
[image]

but he is not in the list(nodetool status) somehow..

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

192.168.0.35    Node2
192.168.0.36    Node3

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: can you tell me what's in :etc/hosts?

Comment: Can they ping each other?  Do they have the same `cluster_name` in the .yaml?

Comment: what is in seeds: list in cassandra.yaml? The seeds should be the same in both nodes. Start the seed node 1st, wait till it's running and then start the other node.

Comment: @Whitefret I edited post

Comment: @Aaron yes they can, yes same cluster name 'Test Cluster'

Comment: @LHWizard I know and thats what I did but not communicate each other